# How to identify all listening ports on a server/network interface in Erlang without using a port scanner?

Tags: erlang

Given a network interface ( inet_x ), is there a native way in erlang to identify all listening ports on such interface ?

It is possible to implement a network scanning function that scans the ip-addresses for such a network interface from ports A to B ( scanner:scan( IpToScan, StartPort, EndPOrt ) ) , but it is fairly slow to achieve these results.

Is there a faster/more native way to achive this ? I am in particular interested in getting a list that indicates results similar to the shell command. The import aspect of this result is also that the ports indicate reveal how it is listening, for example the ( * ) indicates all DNS/ip-address

**netstat - a | grep LISTEN**

```
tcp4       0      0  *.15672                *.*                    LISTEN   
tcp46      0      0  *.52791                *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp46      0      0  *.8181                 *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp46      0      0  *.http-alt             *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp46      0      0  *.sun-as-jmxrmi        *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp46      0      0  *.websm                *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp46      0      0  *.eforward             *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp46      0      0  *.9095                 *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  *.6379                 *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0  localhost.55202        *.*                    LISTEN
```

Also, although it is easy to use the **os module**, I would like to avoid it. Capturing the OS result of netstat -a would be easy, but not cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that netstat is used to provide a friendly, queryable interface over kernel networking data-structures and therefore, all the information displayed will be from the local--never remote--computer. `nmap`, if I read your request as requiring information from remote computers correctly, would be more inline with `scanner:scan/3`. I'm vague on its internal details, but where `nmap` employs ICMP you could mimic with [`gen_icmp`](https://github.com/msantos/gen_icmp) or used [procket](https://github.com/msantos/procket) more generally.

That said, if you have a naive implementation of `scanner:scan/3` but find it too slow, have you considered running one or all of the scan pings in parallel? A parallel map implementation might do the trick, or you could run wild with OTP and a single requestor process / many worker proceses model, where each worker performs the slow ping and, on finish, sends a message to the requestor process.